# First time running a ubuntu server is it possible I have nginx installed in two places?

Tags: nginx

I have two paths:

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

Both contain an .conf file, is it possible I have nginx installed in two locations? When I edit the first /etc/ conf file, I can control what is served, it appears the /opt conf file is ignored. Why?

conf 1:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    access_log  /var/www/mydomain/logs/access.log;

    root /var/www/mydomain/;
    index me.html me.js;
}
~
```

**conf 2** (ignored at /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/passenger-3.0.11;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p0/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  www.mydomain.com;
        root         /var/www/hello/releases/current/public/;
        passenger_enabled on;
       }
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you only have one installation.

**/opt/local/nginx/conf** is where the base configuration for the nginx server is.

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled** is where you'd symlink site you want to be active (from **/etc/nginx/sites-available**.

/etc/nginx/sites-available should contain the individual conf files for virtual hosts.

There should be one file in the sites-available folder (if you haven't added any more). That will be the one being used. It may not be named ending .conf